# Построение спектра звукового сигнала в элементе chart

Tags: c#

Я выполнил быстрое преобразование Фурье звукового файла wav и получил массив complex X, как теперь его правильно представить на графике в виде спектра?

Я написал такой код, но не могу теперь понять, как правильно сопоставить амплитуду определённой частоте

```
// Метод построения графика в частотной области
public void Draw_Signal_In_FrequencyDomain(Complex[] waveData)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < waveData.Length; i++)
    {
        chart_View_FrequencyDomain.Series[0].Points.AddXY();
    } 
}
```

Вот я получил значения массива Complex X, используя этот код:

```
   `// Вычисление поворачивающего модуля e^(-i*2*PI*k/N)        
    private static Complex w(int k, int N)
    {
        if (k % N == 0) return 1;
        double arg = -2 * Math.PI * k / N;
        return new Complex(Math.Cos(arg), Math.Sin(arg));
    }

    // Метод, осуществляющий быстрое преобразование Фурье        
    public static Complex[] FFT(Complex[] x)
    {
        Complex[] X;
        int N = x.Length;
        if (N == 2)
        {
            X = new Complex[2];
            X[0] = x[0] + x[1];
            X[1] = x[0] - x[1];
        }
        else
        {
            Complex[] x_even = new Complex[N / 2];
            Complex[] x_odd = new Complex[N / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
            {
                x_even[i] = x[2 * i];
                x_odd[i] = x[2 * i + 1];
            }
            Complex[] X_even = FFT(x_even);
            Complex[] X_odd = FFT(x_odd);
            X = new Complex[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
            {
                X[i] = X_even[i] + w(i, N) * X_odd[i];
                X[i + N / 2] = X_even[i] - w(i, N) * X_odd[i];
            }
        }                        
        return X;
    }`
```

[значения массива Complex X после выполнения БПФ](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Lkqk/72jqE7pJ6)

Я применил код, написанный в комментарии, у меня получилось такое изображение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `foreach (Complex complex in waveData)
      chart_View_FrequencyDomain.Series[0].Points.AddXY(complex.Real, complex.Imaginary);` ?